# Stack implemantation in c++ using linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

 struct node
 {
   int data;   //data
   node *next; //link
 };

 class stack // stack using linked list
 {
  public:
  node *top; // top element of stack

  public:
   stack()
   {
     top= NULL;
   }

   void push(int value)
   {
     node *temp  = new node; // create a new node
     temp-> data = value;
     temp-> next = NULL;
   if(top==NULL)          //  stack is empty
    {
      top=temp;
      temp=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      temp-> next = top;
      top=temp;
      temp=NULL;
    }
  }
  //template <class X>
  void pop()
  {
    if(top==NULL)
    {
      cout<<"\nStackOverflow "<<endl;
      cout<<"Program Terminated "<<endl;
      exit (0);
    }
    else
    {
      top=top->next;
    }

  }

  void display()
  {

    node *temp=new node;
    temp=top;

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
      cout<<temp->data<<" ";
      temp = temp-> next;
    }
    while(top==NULL)

     { 
        cout<<"\nStack is Empty "<<endl;  
        exit (0);

     }



  }
};

int main()
{
   stack a;

  a.push(5);
  a.display();
  a.push(10);
  a.display();
  a.pop();
  a.pop();
  a.push(20);
  a.display();
  a.pop();
  a.display();
  return 0;
}
```

The Output of this code is 5 10 5 20 Stack is Empty.

Which is wrong output and the correct output is 5 10 20 Stack is Empty..

Anyone tell me why this errors occured.

The Refrence of the code :[[Implementation of stack using Templates and And Linked List in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541686/implementation-of-stack-using-templates-and-and-linked-list-in-c][1])

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your `display` function have a memory leak.

Comment: As for your problem, you push two values, then pop both values (making the stack empty), then push one value and pop that value again making the stack empty. What else did you expect? Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Comment: dispaly() leaks memory somewhere iknow but how can i overcome with that

Comment: Why do you create a new `node` in `display()`?

Comment: @AkkiêThakur Just change `node *temp=new node;` to `node *temp;`. There's no need to allocate a node there because the very next line says `temp=top;` Your version allocates a node and then throws it away, a.k.a a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.push(5);     // Stack:  5
a.display();   // Output: new: 5
a.push(10);    // Stack:  10 5
a.display();   // Output: old: 5 new: 10 5
a.pop();       // Stack:  5
a.pop();       // Stack:  empty
a.push(20);    // Stack:  20
a.display();   // Output: old: 5 10 5 new: 20
a.pop();       // Stack:  empty
a.display();   // Output: old: 5 10 5 20 new:
```

---

> ```
> stack()
> {
>     top= NULL;  // use initializ list instead of assignment
>                 // in constructors body
> }
> ```

-->

```
stack() : top{ nullptr } {}
```

---

> ```
> void pop()
> {
>     if (top == NULL)
>     {
>         cout << "\nStackOverflow " << endl;
>         cout << "Program Terminated " << endl;
>         exit(0);  // don't use exit() in C++ if there are other ways!
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         top = top->next; // the memory top pointed to
>                          // before the assignment leaks!
>     }
> }
> ```

-->

```
void pop()
{
    if (!top) {
        cout << "Pop on empty stack!\n";
        return;
    }

    node *old_top = top;
    top = top->next;
    delete old_top;
}
```

---

> ```
> void display()
> {
>     node *temp = new node;  // no need to allocate a node in a
>                             // function that should only make output
>     temp = top;             // the memory temp points to before the
>                             // assignment leaks
>
>     while (temp != NULL)
>     {
>         cout << temp->data << " ";
>         temp = temp->next;
>     }
>     while (top == NULL)  // why a loop?
>     {
>         cout << "\nStack is Empty " << endl;
>         exit (0);   // again ...
>     }
> }
> ```

-->

```
void display() const
{
    if (!top) {
        std::cout << "Stack is empty!\n";
        return;
    }

    for(node *current = top; current; current = current->next)
        cout << current->data << ' ';
}
```

Comment: sir when i implemented your code it shows error   in  pop().

Comment: display () is well implemented sir. Overall thank you sir for your help

Comment: @AkkiêThakur "it shows error in pop()" yes, there was a } missing.

Comment: but sir it shows the output 5 10 5 20  Stack is empty!  is this true sir

Comment: @sir why this print 5 before 20 in the output

Comment: @AkkiêThakur I edited my answer. Perhaps you understand now.

Answer (score 6):

No, the output is correct.

```
a.push(5);
a.display();
```

This displays the first `5`.

```
a.push(10);
a.display();
```

The `5` is still on the stack, so now this displays the `10` and then the `5`.

```
a.pop();
a.pop();
a.push(20);
a.display();
```

Now everything is removed, the `20` is added and the displayed, so this should just display `20`.

And then the empty stack is printed with

```
a.pop();
a.display();
```

So put together, it should display `5 10 5 20 Stack is Empty`.

Comment: sir i think the correct output will be 5 10 20 Stack is Empty

Comment: Nah, the `5` is correctly printed twice. You put the `5` on the stack and call `display()` twice before popping the `5` off the stack, so it is printed both times.

Comment: `a.push(5);
  a.display();
  a.push(10);
  a.display();` you call display twice with 5 on the stack. So it will be printed twice. The output of this code is 5 10 5, as you see.

Comment: @AkkiêThakur I'm guessing that you think display should show the last item pushed onto the stack, but it doesn't it shows the whole stack.